# Can someone help me understand why a cache hit reads out this specific data

Tags: caching

I'm following an example of virtual memory to physical memory in my textbook. Could someone explain to me what dictates which cache value gets read, or is it just always the first value. [image: physical address]

[image: cache table]

I understand everything up till the end with the cache value. I'm a bit confused as to what dictates why it reads 0x36 as opposed to something else in the same set like 0x72.